# How to see missed VLOOKUP key value?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a VLOOKUP between 2 columns of 2 different sheets. 
The following code does vlookup function and inserts the result in column K.

The thing that i can't manage, how in case of error (N/A value) to see a message box, saying which keys were not found, without stopping a vlookup for following values that are after missing key? AND in case there were not missing keys to return a message box, "All keys are present".

```
Sub MissedKeyCheck()
On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow, LastRow1 As Long
Dim i As String
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetA")

LastRow = Sheets("SheetA").Range("B" & Sheets("SheetA").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow1 = Sheets("SheetB").Range("C" & Sheets("SheetB").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Table1 = Sheets("SheetA").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Table2 = Sheets("SheetB").Range("C3:C" & LastRow1)

Dept_Row = Sheets("SheetA").Range("K2").Row
Dept_Clm = Sheets("SheetA").Range("K2").Column

For Each cl In Table1
  Sheets("SheetA").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 1, False)
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl

MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
  MsgBox "Key: " & " is not present in the SheetB"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this before it to disable error:

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("SheetA").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 1, False)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  ' do something with error
End If

' turn error trapping back on
On Error Goto 0
```

UPDATE

```
Sub MissedKeyCheck()
On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow, LastRow1 As Long
Dim i As String
Dim blnError as Boolean
Dim strMissingKeys as String
blnError = false

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetA")

LastRow = Sheets("SheetA").Range("B" & Sheets("SheetA").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow1 = Sheets("SheetB").Range("C" & Sheets("SheetB").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Table1 = Sheets("SheetA").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Table2 = Sheets("SheetB").Range("C3:C" & LastRow1)

Dept_Row = Sheets("SheetA").Range("K2").Row
Dept_Clm = Sheets("SheetA").Range("K2").Column

For Each cl In Table1
  On Error Resume Next
  Sheets("SheetA").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 1, False)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' do something with error
      blnError=True
      strMissingKeys = strMissingKeys & cl & ","
    End If

    ' turn error trapping back on
    On Error Goto MyErrorHandler

  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl

If blnError = True Then
   MsgBox "Error found in keys: " & vbCrlf & strMissingKeys
Else
   MsgBox "No keys missing..."
End If



MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
  MsgBox "Key: " & " is not present in the SheetB"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand well where to put this part and how to define that cell where the key is not present

Comment: Thanks a lot, i see now. The only problem when i try to run a code with F8, i can see that when `Err.Number<> 0` and `blnError = True` , it returns cl as empty and does not return strMissingKeys value

Comment: I may have mispelt my variable as c1 (one) and not cl...cl can't be empty, you are iterating over it.  i.e.  strMissingKeys = strMissingKeys & cl & ","

Comment: put Option Explicit at the top of your module, it then picks up variable mis-spellings.